# Clean up and Refactor react code to increase performance

Tags: javascript, react.js, react-native

I am new in coding in React and I have just joined a new organization where I need to send my code for review .The functionality is working fine but it seems to me that code in my component has become very lengthy ,also my submithandler method is making me iterate the array a couple of times,I don't know how to do it other way.Is there any way I can shorten my code to make it look better and increase the performance??Currently its taking a long time to show the data after i click submit ,looks like iteration oof array is taking time.

Also,If i close the browser after clicking the submit button, the ajax pending request is still in progress.I want to end the request and stop loading once i close the browser or navigate to other page.myRequestor is a third party library of my organization that can be used to send a request.Please help me shorten the code and fix the pending ajax request issue.Below is the code that I have tried to do.

```
const propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  tenant: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any),
  myRequestor: PropTypes.object, // eslint-disable-line react/forbid-prop-types
  };


let myRequestor = null;

const CallerUtil = () => {
myRequestor = React.useContext(MyRequestorContext);
return <ApplicationLoadingOverlay isOpen backgroundStyle="clear" />;
}


class ReadinessComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        body: '',
        tenant: null,
        error: null,
        errorMsg: '', 
        isOpen: false,
        showTable: false,
        isInvalid: false,
        isLoading: false,
        tenantId: '',
        items: [],
        tenantItems : null
    };

    this.onChangeTenantDropDown = this.onChangeTenantDropDown.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitHandler = this.onSubmitHandler.bind(this);
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
    this.tenantIdHandler = this.tenantIdHandler.bind(this);
    this.onClose = this.onClose.bind(this);
    this.addNewTenant = this.addNewTenant.bind(this);
    this.fetchInitial = this.fetchInitial.bind(this);
   }

componentDidMount() {
  this.mounted = true;
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  this.fetchInitial();

  }
componentWillUnmount(){
    
    this.mounted = false;

  }

onChangeTenantDropDown(value) {
    this.setState({
        tenant: value,
    });

  const info = this.state.tenantItems.find(function (t) { return t.name == value })
  this.setState({
    tenantId: info.id,
  });

}

  onSubmitHandler() {
    if (this.state.body == '') {
      this.setState({ isInvalid: true });
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    const params = {
      "tenantId": this.state.tenantId,
      "tenantShortName": this.state.tenant,
      "contactName": this.state.body
    }

    const { request } = myRequestor.get({
      url: '/getReadinessCheck',
      params: params,
    });

   // request.then(async ({ data }) => {
      request.then(({ data }) => {
      console.log(this.mounted);
      if (!this.mounted) {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        return;
      }
        
      console.log(data);
      
      let abc = data.find(vrsn => vrsn.name === 'TENANT_ERROR');         
      if (abc === undefined) {
        this.setState({ error: 'Failure', errorMsg:'Invalid Tenant',isLoading: false, isOpen: true, showTable: false, body: '', tenantId: ''});
        return;
      }
      let readinessResp = data.map(version => (version.latest === true ? { ...version, name: version.name.concat('_LATEST') } : version))
      readinessResp.sort(function (a, b) {
        var textA = a.name.toUpperCase();
        var textB = b.name.toUpperCase();
        return textA.localeCompare(textB);
      });

      this.setState({ items: readinessResp, error: 'Success', showTable: true, isLoading: false });
    }).catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error: 'Failure', errorMsg:'Failure', isLoading: false, isOpen: true, showTable: false ,body: '', tenantId: '' });
      });
    
  }


onChangeHandler(event) {
    this.setState({
        body: event.target.value,
    });
}

tenantIdHandler(event) {
  this.setState({
    tenantId: event.target.value,
  });
}

onClose() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        isOpen: !prevState.isOpen,
    }));
}


addNewTenant(shortName,tenantId){
  const newTenantShortName = shortName;
  const newTenantId = tenantId;
  const newTenant = {'name':newTenantShortName, 'id':newTenantId};
  this.setState({
    tenantItems: [...this.state.tenantItems, newTenant]
});     

}

fetchInitial() {
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  const { request } = myRequestor.get({
    url: '/tenants'
  });
   
  request
  .then(({ data }) => {
    if(data[0].hasOwnProperty("error")){
      this.setState({ error: 'Failure', errorMsg:data[0]['error'], isOpen: true, isLoading: 
   false,tenantItems: [{'name':'Default', 'id':'Default'}]});
      return;
    }

    let tenantsList = data;
    let tenants =[];
    tenantsList.map(tenant => ( tenants.push({'name':tenant.shortName, 'id':tenant.key})))

  this.setState({
    tenantItems: tenants,isLoading: false
  });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    this.setState({ error: 'Failure', isOpen: true, isLoading: false});
  });
  }


  render() {
      const {
   error, isOpen, body,showTable
       } = this.state;

if (this.state.tenantItems === null) {
  return <CallerUtil />;
  }

if(this.state.isLoading){
    return <ApplicationLoadingOverlay isOpen backgroundStyle="clear" />;
}

if (showTable) {
    return (<div>
    <h1>Readiness Status</h1>
    <ReadinessComponentView readinessInfo={this.state.items} /></div>);
}

return (
  <div className="ruleSupportEvaluation">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Column>
          <Heading level={1}>Readiness Check</Heading>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Column className="ruleSupportEvaluation" large={3} medium={3}>
          <div>
            <Heading className="info" level={3}>About</Heading>
            <Divider />
            <Text className="description" fontSize={18}>
              Readiness Check
            </Text>
          </div>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column className="ruleSupportEvaluation" large={8} medium={8}>
          <div>
            <div className="readinessComponent">
            <Tenant
              tenant={this.state.tenantItems}
              change={this.onChangeTenantDropDown}
            />
            <ModalManagerExample addNewTenant={this.addNewTenant} />
            </div>
            <InputField type="text" label="Tenant-Id" value={this.state.tenantId} placeholder="Tenant Id" onChange={this.tenantIdHandler}/>
            <InputElement isInvalid ={this.state.isInvalid} change={this.onChangeHandler} value={body} />                
            <Submit click={this.onSubmitHandler} />
            
            {error === 'Failure' &&
              (
                <Notification
                  errorMessage={this.state.errorMsg}
                  close={this.onClose}
                  isOpen={isOpen}
                />
              )
             }
          </div>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
  </div>
);
     }
 }

ReadinessComponent.propTypes = propTypes;

export default ReadinessComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const info = this.state.tenantItems.find(function (t) { return t.name == value })
// could be more concise with lambda
const info = this.state.tenantItems.find(t => t.name == value)
```

```
let tenantsList = data;
let tenants =[];
tenantsList.map(tenant => ( tenants.push({'name':tenant.shortName, 'id':tenant.key})))
// you're implementing map using map+push here
// can be simplified
const tenants = data.map(tenant=>({
  name:tenant.shortName,
  id:tenant.key
)})
```

These could all be const.

```
let abc = data.find(vrsn => vrsn.name === 'TENANT_ERROR');  
var textA = a.name.toUpperCase();
var textB = b.name.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.But I see my submitHandler method code is making me iterate the response a couple of times.Could you please help me on how can i shorten the submitHandler method code?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything awful going on with the array. Have you ruled out the readiness check or possibly the React items re-render for performance bottlenecks?

Comment: The reason I am asking is because after I click the submit button it sends the Ajax request and if I close the browser or navigate to other page before the request gets completed,the page still keeps sending the request unless it is completed .I tried to stop the pending Ajax request by using componentwillunmount but I get a warning saying Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks